# Spring Data MongoDB: Dynamic field name converter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

How do I set the MongoDB Document field name dynamically (without using `@Field`)?

```
@Document
public class Account {
    private String username;
}
```

For example, field names should be capitalized. Result:

```
{"USERNAME": "hello"}
```

And I want this dynamic converter to work with any document, so a solution without using generics.

Comment: not clear what u are asking . In database you want the field names to be stored in capitals?

Comment: Basically, I just want to run the field names through a function. Maybe something like remove vowels so it saves memory in the database.

Answer (score 1):

This a bit strange requirement. You can make use of Mongo Listener Life cycle events [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.mapping-usage.events).

```
@Component
public class MongoListener extends AbstractMongoEventListener<Account> {

  @Override
  public void onBeforeSave(BeforeSaveEvent<Account> event) {
     DBObject dbObject = event.getDBObject();
     String username = (String) dbObject.get("username");// get the value

     dbObject.put("USERNAME", username);
     dbObject.removeField("username");
     // You need to go through each and every field recursively in  
     // dbObject and then remove the field and then add the Field you  
     // want(with modification) 
  }
}
```

This is a bit cluncky, but I believe there is no clean way to do this.